# RDB has an AOF tail, redis does not start

Tags: redis

I have a redis version 6.2.6 installed and it doesn't start.

I am getting this logs messages:

```
1610:C 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.380 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1610:C 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.380 # Redis version=6.2.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1610, just started
1610:C 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.380 # Configuration loaded
1610:M 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.381 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1610:M 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.381 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1610:M 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.381 # Server initialized
1610:M 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.381 * Reading RDB preamble from AOF file...
1610:M 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.381 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.6
1610:M 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.381 * RDB age 1759685 seconds
1610:M 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.381 * RDB memory usage when created 217.78 Mb
1610:M 18 Jul 2023 10:06:57.381 * RDB has an AOF tail
1610:signal-handler (1689689217) Received shutdown signal during loading, exiting now.
```

These are my redis configuration file parameters:

```
protected-mode no
daemonize yes
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
port 6379
tcp-backlog 128
bind 0.0.0.0
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
loglevel debug
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
databases 4
save ""
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /var/lib/redis
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100
requirepass 9207335928d94703b4515eb8be2a86e5
maxmemory 6GB
maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

If I restart the service I don't get any error but it is not possible to connect to redis-cli.

This is my redis-server status:

```
redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2023-07-18 10:28:09 EDT; 1min 8s ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 2032 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2012 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2012 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Status does not show any error.